# How to use dger (BLAS) in C

Tags: blas

I'm struggling with using dger() correctly in C. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "blas.h"

int main() {
    double a[4*5] = {  1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                     6, 7, 8, 9,10,
                    11,12,13,14,15,
                    16,17,18,19,20
                  };
    double x[4]  = {2,3,4,5};
    double y[5] = {7,8,9,10,11};
    int tm=4, tn=5, tone=1;

    dger(&tm, &tn, &tone, x, &tone, y, &tone, a, &tm);
}
```

The code compiles without error but when I execute the code, it crashes. I don't really get more details why the code crashes because I'm writing a mex C file (MATLAB C-code) -  I have omitted the overhead of the mex entry function and so on.

Comment: You probably need to enable compiler warnings, and then the issue would become clear.

Comment: Oh you were totally right. I wasn't aware that `int` in the description ( http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d15/group__double__blas__level2_ga458222e01b4d348e9b52b9343d52f828.html#ga458222e01b4d348e9b52b9343d52f828 ) needs to be `ptrdiff_t` in C.

Comment: If you are going to be using this code in a MATLAB Mex routine with the MATLAB supplied BLAS library, note that MATLAB gives you a defined integer type to use for the BLAS interface to ensure compatability with the library, which is mwSignedIndex.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your arguments: https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d15/group__double__blas__level2_ga458222e01b4d348e9b52b9343d52f828.html
In particular you are missing the `alpha` parameter (passing `&tone` instead).

Comment: Yeah, like i supplied (like I supplied tm, tn, ...) it but I figured out (thanks to @underscore_d ) that it mustn't be of the type `int` but of the type `ptrdiff_t`